# How to query for all records created today (midnight UTC..Now)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a created_at query range that will capture all records created from midnight UTC (db default) to now. In the past I've been able to query for time ranges with:

```
created_at => (24.hours.ago..Time.now)
```

But adjusting the above for the new use case does not work:

```
created_at => (Date.today..Time.now)
```

Any suggestions on how I can update the created_at range to be all records today / not in the last 24 hours?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
created_at => (DateTime.now.at_beginning_of_day.utc..Time.now.utc)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can try for below line as well.

```
ModelName.all :condition => ["DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now]
```

OR In Rails 3

```
Model.where "DATE(created_at) = DATE(?)", Time.now
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think time zone should be considered.

`where(:created_at => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day.utc..Time.zone.now.end_of_day.utc)`

And Rails will change time to utc time automatically, so the following is also ok.

`where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)`

Answer (score 2):

Since Rails5.1, A new method `Date#all_day` was introduced, which returns `a range of a day`.

Instead of:

```rb
where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

An elegant way is:

```rb
where(created_at: Date.today.all_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.today.beginning_of_day.utc..Date.today.end_of_day.utc
```